# beginner python number generator game

Tags: python

I am creating a number generator game in python, and I am using the input function, however it will not allow me to input anything then I try to input a number. I am also unsure if my code is right in general. Also if there is anything I could add to the game please let me know.

```
import random
digits = list(range(10))
random.shuffle(digits)
digits=list(digits[:3])
print(digits)
print("number generated")
guess= ""

while guess != digits:
    guess = input("What is your guess?:  ")
    guess=list(guess.split(","))
    if guess[0] == digits[0] or guess[1] == digits[1] or guess[2] == digits[2]:
        print("you have matched atleast one correctly")
    if guess[0] == digits[0] or guess[1] == digits[1] or guess[2] == digits[2]:
        print("you have matched atleast one correctly")
    elif guess[0] != digits[0] and guess[1] != digits[1] and guess[2] != digits[2]:
        print("No numbers matched")
    elif guess == digits:
        print("You guessed correct!")
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a string and your `digits` are integers, so you need to do a conversion before comparing them:

```py
guess = input("What is your guess?:  ")
guess = guess.split(",")  # Removed unnecessary list conversion here
guess = [int(i) for i in guess]
```

Also, it seems you have accidentally duplicated the "one digit matched" `if` condition, otherwise looks like you are on the right track

Comment: I added the guess = [int(i) for i in guess] and it still would not allow me to enter an input.